# Are there any identities for binomial sum-products of the form $\sum_{k} \binom{k}{r} \cdot \binom{r+a}{k-b} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, binomial-coefficients

I'm looking for identities for series of the form: $$\sum_{k} \binom{k}{r} \cdot \binom{r+a}{k-b} ,$$ where $a, b,r \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. The summation index $k$ may start at any positive integer. While I've found a number of [identities](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Summations_of_Products_of_Binomial_Coefficients) for sum-products of binomial coefficients, I have not been able to find one for this particular series.

Comment: What is the upper bound for $k$?

Comment: @ZAhmed I think if $k$ starts at $m$, then the upper bound is $k=m+a-b$